# Add server to known_hosts

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bash, puppet

**I would like to add github.com to the known_hosts file from the command line** as I am creating a puppet manifest to provision a remote server.

I have tried:

```
"ssh-keyscan -H github.com > /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
```

But when the server tries to access github:

```
Failed to add the RSA host key for IP address '207.97.227.239' to the list 
of known hosts (/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

I've also tried:

```
"ssh-keyscan -H github.com,207.97.227.239 > /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"`
```

But accessing github throws:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

I'm sure this is of no additional use but if I ssh my server and then ssh github and follow the steps I get the following message `Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of known hosts` and then it will work perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: The 'failed to add' message indicates there could be a permissions issue on `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts`.  Is it writable by your user?

Comment: You would most likely want `>>` to append instead of `>` to overwrite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We handle this problem by putting the known_hosts file on the puppet server and serving the file directly out of puppet:

```
file{
  "/home/appuser/.ssh/known_hosts":
  owner => "appuser",
  group => "appuser",
  mode => 755,
  source => "puppet:///modules/ssh/known_hosts",
  require => File["/home/appuser"];
}
```

This copies the correctly formatted known_hosts file from the puppet repo, sets the user accordingly, and ensures it has correct permissions. Works well for us.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you not using the `sshkey` resource to publish key(s) directly to the system wide known_hosts file?

Comment: @Zoredache Because I'd never heard of that facility before.

Comment: Ah, I like the [sshkey](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#sshkey) better then replacing the entire file since it allows me to add/remove individual keys and still permitting local changes, which is somewhat needed in my environment.

Comment: Thanks that work a treat! @Zoredache sshkey looks great but it would be nice if it would let you specify directory/file name!

Comment: sshkey does let you specify the directory/file name.  Just use target => "fullpath/to/filename"

Answer (score 3):

This is mentioned in the comments to the accepted answer, but I just ran into this and thought that this much cleaner solution deserves its own answer.

Puppet's core [sshkey](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#sshkey) type installs keys into the server-wide /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts file without having to clobber the whole file.  For this case:

```
sshkey {'github':
  name => 'github.com',
  ensure => present,
  key => '[GitHub key (just the part after ssh-rsa, starting with AAA)]',
  type => 'ssh-rsa',
}
```

Will install it nicely.